# Find number of leaf nodes in a binary tree having depth D using array implementation

Tags: c, data-structures, binary-tree

**C** code to find the number of leaf nodes in a tree with depth d.
Hint is to use array implementation of binary tree.

Comment: This "question" is so bad it's not even funny any more. For starters, read the FAQ and fix your English.

Comment: not a homework sir... i cn find out the leaf nodes in a binarytree... but i cant find out for a tree having depth d usingarray implementation

Comment: nybody knows the shortest method?

Comment: not specified... its just a binary tree no other property...

Comment: @Skurmedel - I hope that was a rhetorical question :)

Comment: "hint is to use array implementation of binary tree" - No, hint is not to use StackOverflow as "do my work/homework for me when i'm too lazy to even word the question properly"

Comment: @DVK: Yeah the last one was pretty rhetorical :D

Answer (score 2):

ignoring the hint...

```
int FindNumLeafs(Tree t)
{
  if(t == null)
  { 
    return 0;
  }

  if(t.LeftSon == null && t.RightSon == null)
  {
    return 1;
  }

  return FindNumLeafs(t.LeftSon) + FindNumLeafs(t.RightSon);

}
```

Comment: i know this linkedlist implementation and need to know the array implementation...

Comment: @user420878: Why would it be any different? You just traverse it slightly differently.

Comment: 1. this has nothing to do with linked lists. 2. there are several way's to implement a tree in an array. 3. the principle remains in all implementations you just go through the tree, and count leafs...

Comment: if(t.LeftSon == null && t.RightSon == null)
  {
    return 1;
  }
it should be this.. shouldnt it?

Comment: @user420878 - yes obviously, i fixed the answer...

Answer (score 0):

Height of a balanced binary tree is given by log2(n). Therefore, leaf nodes = 2^d.

Comment: that's true only if it's a balanced tree.